# Is there a way to generate a Unique Identifier (in SQL Server newid()) in Excel 2007

Tags: sql-server, excel

Can you create a unique identifier in Excel 2007. I'm looking for the same value generate by the SQL Server function newid().

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [CoCreateGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568(VS.85).aspx) API function

```
Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32" (ByRef GUID As Byte) As Long

Public Function CreateGUID()
   Dim ID(0 To 15) As Byte
   Dim N As Long
   Dim GUID As String
   Dim Res As Long
   Res = CoCreateGuid(ID(0))
   For N = 0 To 15
      GUID = GUID & IIf(ID(N) < 16, "0", "") & Hex$(ID(N))
   Next N
   CreateGUID = GUID
End Function
```